# Не отвечает скрипт node.js

Tags: node.js, vps

Есть скрипт index.js:

```
const http = require('http')
const port = 3000
const host = '00.00.000.000'
http.createServer((req, res) => {
  console.log('Test')
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'})
  res.write('Hello World!')
  res.end()
}).listen(port, host, 511, () => {
  let date = new Date()
  console.log('Runned: ' + date.getTime())
});
```

Запускаю скрипт через ssh, захожу по ip сервера vps: http://00.00.000.000:3000/ или http://00.00.000.000:3000/index.js (ip сервера здесь бутафорный) и страница бесконечно загружается (в конце концов выдавая ошибку "Не удается получить доступ к сайту"). Пробовал разные порты, ошибок в консоли нет. При запуске скрипта через консоль выходит сообщение 'Runned: ...', но блок "console.log('Test')..." будто вообще не срабатывает при запросе через браузер. Через 80 порт спокойно грузится файл скрипта(не исполненный). Пробовал разные вариации подобного кода, но все равно не хочет работать. OC - ubuntu 18.04.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Попробуйте с машины где запущен скрипт проверить. `curl localhost:3000` или `wget localhost:3000`

Comment: curl: Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused
wget: Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:3000... failed: Connection refused.

Comment: Эм, а скрипт-то запустили?

Comment: Ещё можно попробовать просто убрать параметр host в вызове listen.

Comment: С запущенным скриптом проверил. Порт также был закрыт, пока значение хоста не изменил на localhost. В таком случае через curl выдает "Hello world", wget тоже коннектится, код 200 получает, в общем работает. Но через браузер по-прежнему не работает.

Comment: host из listen убирал, потом по порядку и остальные параметры, кроме порта - все точно также

Comment: Проверьте файрвол

Comment: Опиши пожалуйста вкратце(а лучше подробно) как это сделать, я один день только сисадминю на этом vps'е;)

Comment: вырубил через комаду ufw disable - доступ к скрипту через браузер заработал. Но, я так понимаю, отрубать его полностью - очень плохая идея. Раз дело в нем, то как разрешить доступ по http для данного скрипта?

Comment: Возможно "Запуск сервера IPC от имени root может привести к тому, что путь к серверу станет недоступным для непривилегированных пользователей. Использование readableAllи writableAllсделает сервер доступным для всех пользователей." `server.listen({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 80,
  readableAll: true,
  writableAll: true
});`